# Running describeReport(3-arg); of Salesforce Reports and Dashboard API, gives an error(in the SS). Any idea why could this be happening?

Tags: apex, exception, dashboard, reports-api, analytics-api

[image]

**-------------------------------------------------**

Edit for better error message and methods googleability:

```
Exception occurred - The data you're trying to access is unavailable.

Class.reports.ReportManager.describeReport: line 6, column 1
Class.SaveInvoiceAsCSVFile.saveInvoice: line 44, column 1
Class.PemeWsJobs.execute: line 19, column 1

The data you're trying to access is unavailable.

System.NoDataFoundException
```

*Please consider following before answering*:

- The same code runs when invoked through anonymous code window in devConsole.
- "Run reports" permission is there on profile running this code.
- If I query the records with fields that the report is on, they show up no error.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer, the problem was that the user did not have access in the Folder that contained the report being used in Reports.ReportManager.describeReport(3-argument) call.